# Ordenar posiciones de claves Json

Tags: java, json, spring

Buenas tardes hay la posibilidad de poder ordenar las `claves` de un `JSONArray` en `java`, estoy usando `Spring MVC` y `JSON versión 20180813`.
Mi código **`Persona_Dao`** para obtener los valores de mi **BD**.

```
public static List<Persona> listarPersonas() throws SQLException{
    List<Persona> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(Conexion.conectar());
    try{
        String sql = "call mostrar_persona();";
        lista = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Persona_RowMapper());
    }catch(DataAccessException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        if(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection() != null){
            jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().close();
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Clase **`Persona_RowMapper()`**, complemento del código anterior.

```
private static class Persona_RowMapper implements RowMapper<Persona>{
    @Override
    public Persona mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        Persona pers = new Persona();
        pers.setCodigo_Pers(rs.getString("codigo_Pers"));
        pers.setNombre_Pers(rs.getString("nombre_Pers"));
        pers.setApellido_Pat_Pers(rs.getString("apellido_Pat_Pers"));
        pers.setApellido_Mat_Pers(rs.getString("apellido_Mat_Pers"));
        return pers;
    }
}
```

Este es mi código **java** dentro de un **controlador** con `@ResponseBody`.

```
List<Persona> datos = Persona_Dao.listarPersonas();
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(datos);
return ja.toString();
```

Como pueden observar los datos los obtengo desde mi **BD** y todo va bien, pero el único inconveniente lo que muestro a continuación.
Así se ve mi resultado **"Json"** en la página web.

```
[  
 {
  "codigo_Pers":"P-001",  
  "apellido_Mat_Pers":"Rodriguez",  
  "apellido_Pat_Pers":"Castilla",  
  "nombre_Pers":"Juan"
 }  
]
```

pero prefiero que se muestre de esta manera.

```
[  
  {
   "codigo_Pers":"P-001",  
   "nombre_Pers":"Juan",  
   "apellido_Pat_Pers":"Castilla",  
   "apellido_Mat_Pers":"Rodriguez"
  }  
]
```

Entonces habría una forma de solucionar este problema desde `java`.
**Como siempre cualquier respuesta es apreciada.**

Comment: Sería más fácil si en la consulta SQL ordenas los datos como los requieres, ¿Tienes acceso al código de esa consulta?

Comment: Hola @RafaelBautistaMartinez primero agradecerte por responder, mi código SQL tiene ordenado las columnas de mi tabla pero el `json` los muestra desordenados.

Comment: También podrías ordenar los campos dentro de tu clase `Persona` para mostrarlos en el orden deseado, es muy raro que JSONArray desordene los datos.

Comment: Mi clase `Persona` también esta ordenado, pero talvez nose si es la forma correcta de poder almacenar una `Lista de objetos` a un `JSONArray` tal como lo muestro en la parte superior, o habría otra forma.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de `Persona_Dao.listarPersonas();`, en cuanto a las listas es lo más común.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad el orden de los valores en el json no debe ser importante ya que puedes obtener los datos del json y representarlos visualmente al usuario definiendo otro orden.

Una opción, si usas Jackson puedes hacer uso de la anotación `@JsonPropertyOrder` a tu objeto, definiendo el orden de los campos:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "codigo_Pers", "nombre_Pers", "apellido_Pat_Pers", "apellido_Mat_Pers" })    
public class Persona
{
 ...
 ...
 ...
}
```